# Using TM_SELECTED_TEXT in my custom snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-generation, sublimetext, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

With the November 2016 (version 1.8) release of VSCode [Snippet Variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_snippets) are now supported, specifically TM_SELECTED_TEXT.

This makes me happy as I have used these heavily in both Sublime Text and TextMate.

I can't figure out how to get it to work in VSCode.  I've created the snippet they use as an example:

```
"in quotes": {
    "prefix": "inq",
    "body": "'${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:${1:type_here}}'"
}
```

I then enter some text, highlight it and that's where things start to break.

The idea is highlight some text, run the snippet and then `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:${1:type_here}}` is replaced with the highlighted text.  The problem I'm having is that to run the snippet you need to type the `prefix` value (in this case *inq*) to run the snippet which over-writes your highlighted text which messes everything up.

In Sublime/Textmate I launched the snippet from a keyboard combination which left my text highlighted.

Is there a way, in VSCode, to either make this work as is or launch the snippet from a key combination like was available in Sublime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the word highlighted, press <kbd>F1</kbd> and run the command "Insert Snippet", then select your snippet on the list.

Also you can edit your keybindings by going to *File*>*Preferences*>*Keyboard Shortcuts* and add some shortcut to the "editor.action.showSnippets" command, like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+s",
    "command": "editor.action.showSnippets",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Coming in 1.49 (it is in the Insiders' Build as of this edit) your example will finally work as you expected. See [merged pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/105440).

Vscode will now "remember" your selected text if any, and when you type your snippet prefix, insert it into the `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` variable even though you seemingly over-typed that selected text.

[image: selected text snippet]

---

As of v1.20 this has become easier as a new variable $CLIPBOARD has been added, see [new snippet variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_more-snippet-variables).  So there is no need to assign and run a shortcut - but you must copy the selection to clipboard <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Your example could now be:

```
"in quotes": {
    "prefix": "inq",
    "body": "'$CLIPBOARD:${1:type_here}'"
}
```

Note: `$CLIPBOARD` works. There's no need for the extra curly brackets `{$CLIPBOARD}`.

Comment: Brilliant, I'd give multiple upvotes if possible. Tested on v1.51.1. Didn't work < v1.49

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17780

as per this thread you can assign exact snippet to keybinding by providing `args`.
keybinding example for bootstrap media queries

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "name": "bsup"
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+shift+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "name": "bsup_copy"
    }
},
```

snippet example

```
"bsup": {
    "prefix": "bsup",
    "body": [
        "@include media-breakpoint-up(md){",
        "\t${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Bootstrap media up"
},
"bsup_copy": {
    "prefix": "bsup_copy",
    "body": [
        "${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}",
        "@include media-breakpoint-up(md){",
        "\t${2:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Bootstrap media up + copy selected text"
},
```

**UPD:** moreover - **you can define snippet directly in `keybindings.json`** which seems to be even more convenient for me in some cases

```
{
  "key": "cmd+shift+c",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
     "snippet": "console.log('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}', $TM_SELECTED_TEXT$1);"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using documentation from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets i was able to customize snippets, i am using 'surround with' extension and can put my own snippet into settings.json as follows:

```
"html_h3-name": {
  "label": "h3",
  "description": "wrap by h3 with <a name=''>, top",
  "snippet": "<h3><a name=\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/[\\s]/-/g}\"></a>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\n\t<a class=\"small\" href=\"#top\">top</a>\n</h3>"
```

},

which takes highlighted code in VSCode and creates h3 header from it with a name link:

```
it converts  'aaa bbb ccc' to 
<h3><a name="aaa-bbb-ccc"></a>aaa bbb ccc
    <a class="small" href="#top">top</a>
</h3>
```