# How to - in Visual Studio Code - wrap selection with a tag (div, preferably)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags

Is there a way to select a few lines of code in Visual Studio Code and, somehow, automatically wrap them with a div (or other tag)?

Thank you for any help

Mitsos

Comment: See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305712/836330

Comment: Thanks I will take a look here as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Emmet: Wrap Individual lines with abbreviation`.

If you have a fixed tag you want to use to wrap you can add a keyboard shortcut in `keybindings.json`

```json
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+d",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapIndividualLinesWithAbbreviation",
    "args": { "abbreviation": "div" }
  }
```