# VS Code costumizing functions and methods colors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to costumize the colors of functions in VScode,
as far as i understand i need to do it in the settings.json file in the workbench.colorCustomizations section.
My question is what property should i use in order to change the color of functions? 
Also is it possible to define a different color for native methods?

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "what key should go here?": "#000000"
  }
}
```

Comment: VSCode has its own tag.

Comment: What language?  And then search for `scopes` and `colorCustomizations` in Stack Overflow `[vscode]`.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305712/836330 which may help depending on your language.

Comment: The `extensions` tag is only for developing extensions ;>}

Comment: language is Javascript. thanks, i will look it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to the answer of Mark,
i found out that in order to costumize the scopes' colors i could use the "Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope" from the Command Palette,
and then use it like so in the settings.json:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.function",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#66d9ef",
                },

            }
        ]
    }
```

creating a new object with scope and settings for each costumization