# How to wrap code with the snippet in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this snippet:

```
"Wrap with React-Fragment": {
    "prefix": "rf",
    "body": [
        "<React.Fragment>${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}</React.Fragment>$1"
    ],
}
```

I want to have it wrap the highlighted text when I type the prefix.
For example, imagine that all these `div`s are highlighted:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Currently it just replaces the text with the body of the snippet. What should I do to make it work?

Note! I am aware of the solution of pressing `F1` and selecting `Insert Snippet`. It is too cumbersome.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48676522/836330.   In v1.49 this will work as you expect.  Select your `div`'s, type your prefix, and voila.

Answer (score 1):

What about assigning a custom key shortcut ? Open keybindings.json (Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts File), and paste:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "langId": "javascript",
    "name": "Wrap with React-Fragment"
  }
}
```